FindInstance for Reals
I am trying to find the total number of solutions to:  Floor[x]*Ceiling[x]=x^2 between 0 and 100
Now when we do this for Integers, it's just fine with a 100 result:
FindInstance[
 Floor[x]*Ceiling[x] == x^2 && 0 < x <= 100 , {x}, Integers, 200]

Now why does it not work for Reals?
When I put mx of 200, it only gives me 1 random solution of 63 with the typical warning "Warning: FindInstance found only 1 instance(s), but it was not able to prove 200 instances do not exist."
FindInstance[
 Floor[x]*Ceiling[x] == x^2 && 0 < x <= 100 , {x}, Reals, 200]

But if I down the limit to 20, then it gives a series of solutions with #1's (what does that even mean)?
Any way to make this right to gove a full solution?
Thanks!

Try command:   ?Root ?

It works in MMA version 14.0

version 12.2, 13.3.1,14.0 works but 11.3 not.

$MaxPiecewiseCases = 200;
Solve[Floor[x]*Ceiling[x] == x^2 && 0 < x <= 100, x]
Length[%]


{{x -> 1}, {x -> 2}, ... , {x -> Sqrt[8742]}, {x -> Sqrt[8930]}}

199


Thank you so much! Sorry I was away for a while....
